# calculate mirt model with some fixed item parameters

Tags: item-response-theory

I would like to calculate a 2pl mirt model with parameters for some items fixed.
They come from a previous model.

```
#load LSAT section 7 data and compute 1 factor models
data <- expand.table(LSAT7)
fit <- mirt(data, 1)
cfs<-as.data.frame(matrix(head(coef(fit, IRTpars = TRUE, as.data.frame = TRUE),-2), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)[,1:2])
colnames(cfs) <- c("Discr", "Diff")
row.names(cfs)<-colnames(data)
cfs
```

The code above gives the following result:

```
       Discr   Diff
Item.1 0.988 -1.879
Item.2 1.081 -0.748
Item.3 1.706 -1.058
Item.4 0.765 -0.635
Item.5 0.736 -2.520
```

How could I estimate the model but fixing some item params eg like this?

```
Item.1 1      -2
Item.2 1.5    -1
```

Comment: Probably not the best place to ask programming related questions. And this has been answered elsewhere (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mirt-package) and is documented in multiple areas of the package.

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the right group - I indeed found the answer there - eg. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mirt-package/fix$20parameters/mirt-package/C1NtZwbBSWU/1t4-Eq-k05QJ 
If you would post your comment as an answer I could Accept it.